# SSRS - Matrix Column Subtotals

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to create a report which has some interesting subtotals which I'm struggling with. Here's what I'm looking to create:

```
                                        Col Group A (Currency)
                                        Col Group B (Branch)
Row Group A (Account Group)
Row Group B (Open/Close Balance)        Amount
```

Here's an example of what my data could look like:

```
                                       CAD           CAD           USD
                                       Main          Div A         Div B
Account Rec         Open               100.00        50.00         25.00
Account Rec         Close              123.00        50.00         35.00

Account Pay        etc
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is blank columns after each Col Group without any page breaks. In this example after the CAD currency I'd like to have 4 blank columns to make some calculations (in some cases related to another dataset in the report). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking to add some more columns to the *Currency* group, i.e. in the Designer this will look like:

[image]

With the end result like:

[image]

I've only added two columns here to keep the image from getting too complicated, but you can add as many as you like.

To do this, I just specified that a **Group Footer** be included when creating the *Currency* group, then added another column to the right of the footer row that was created.

Is this the sort of thing you're after?